# Tex error occurred while upgrading octave with brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave, tex

I first installed octave through brew with the instruction on the office website. One day when I entered `brew update && brew upgrade`, octave started to upgrade but one error occurred said

> You don't have a working TeX binary (tex) installed anywhere in your
>   PATH, and texi2dvi cannot proceed without one. If you want to use this
>   script, you'll need to install TeX (if you don't have it) or change
>   your PATH or TEX environment variable (if you do). See the --help
>   output for more details.

So I entered `brew cask install mactex` to install tex and added the `Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin` to the PATH, when I run `tex`, it correctly processed:
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma8c0.png)

Then I run `brew upgrade` but the same error occurred again.

I realized that the `--without-docs` argument may fix this problem but if I want to install docs (since I have already installed tex) what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while installing another program (not octave) and after looking around I found that I needed to install TeTex (http://www.tug.org/teTeX/) or TexLive, however I decided to install TexLive because TeTex is not mantained anymore... 
For me it worked after installing Texlive on the basic configuration. You can follow the instructions over here:

http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html